# How can I get DISTINCT/GROUP BY behavior in UPDATE query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I get an Error: **Error Number: 1242** *Subquery returns more than 1 row*

Because My `UPDATE`'s subquery  produce repeat values. I know `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` can remove repeat values in `SELECT` query.How can I fix it on `UPDATE` query. My query is Here

```
UPDATE 
    product_stock AS S
LEFT JOIN
    product_purchase_item AS I
ON
     S.product_id=I.product_id AND S.product_size=I.product_size
LEFT JOIN
    product_purchases AS P
ON
     I.product_purchase_item_id=P.product_purchase_item_id  
SET
    S.product_size_quantity=S.product_size_quantity+I.quantity
WHERE
    S.product_id=?
AND
    S.product_size=?
```

Suppose, If I  convert  it in `SELECT` query

```
SELECT
 S.*
FROM
 product_stock AS S
LEFT JOIN
 product_purchase_item AS I
ON
 S.product_id=I.product_id AND S.product_size=I.product_size
LEFT  JOIN
 product_purchases AS P
ON
 I.product_purchase_item_id=P.product_purchase_item_id
```

The query return

```
product_stock_id  product_id   product_size product_quantity

10                 216          1            1 
10                 216          1            1
11                 216          5            1
```

But I need(Just a `DISTINCT` keyword can do this in `SELECT` query)

```
product_stock_id  product_id   product_size product_quantity

10                 216          1            1 
11                 216          5            1
```

But,how can I retrieve like above data(UNIQUE VALUES) in my `UPDATE` subquery? is it possible to use `DISTINCT` keyword or like anything in my `UPDATE` query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick. Was there a reason for the product_purchases table to be included because it seems to be redundant in your query?

```
UPDATE product_stock SET product_size_quantity = product_size_quantity + I.quantity

from product_stock
INNER JOIN (select product_id, product_size, sum(quantity) from product_purchase_item group by product_id, product_size) AS I
ON product_stock.product_id=I.product_id AND product_stock.product_size=I.product_size

WHERE product_stock.product_id=?
AND product_stock.product_size=?
```

Comment: yea, I am using a `AFTER INSERT ON` product_purchases `trigger`. So I need product_purchases table. Here my  [change_stock_when_purchases TRIGGER](http://pastebin.com/tcANMhen) . I use `GROUP BY` indirectly in here. but it shows same error

Answer (score 0):

If the data is truly identical, you can simply use `"min()"` without group by/distinct

```
UPDATE 
    product_stock AS S
LEFT JOIN
    product_purchase_item AS I
ON
     S.product_id=I.product_id AND S.product_size=I.product_size
LEFT JOIN
    product_purchases AS P
ON
     I.product_purchase_item_id=P.product_purchase_item_id  
SET
    --   CHANGE HERE ===============================>
    S.product_size_quantity=S.product_size_quantity+MIN(I.quantity)
WHERE
    S.product_id=?
AND
    S.product_size=?
```

Comment: same problem. I can't understand, why you use MIN()?. may be the problem found before `SET`. because here it already get repeat values.