# Error #1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row when update

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, sql-update

This was my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18537760/how-can-i-get-distinct-group-by-behavior-in-update-query/18542231?noredirect=1#18542231). I can't solve problem. I update my code and, I use `GROUP BY` indirectly. but same problem shows. subquery return duplicate values. Actually I made a TRIGGER, So I think if show  trigger, it will be clear to understand

```
--
-- Triggers `product_purchases`
--
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `change_stock_when_purchases`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `change_stock_when_purchases` AFTER INSERT ON `product_purchases`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  DECLARE X INTEGER;
  SET X = (SELECT product_size FROM product_stock WHERE product_id = NEW.product_id );
  IF NEW.product_size =X  THEN
    UPDATE
        product_stock as S1
        INNER JOIN
        (
        SELECT
            S.product_stock_id,I.quantity 
        FROM 
            product_stock AS S
        INNER JOIN
            product_purchase_item AS I 
        ON
            S.product_id=I.product_id AND S.product_size=I.product_size
        INNER JOIN
            product_purchases AS P
        ON
            I.product_purchase_item_id=P.product_purchase_item_id
        WHERE
            P.product_purchase_id=NEW.product_purchase_id
        GROUP BY 
            S.product_stock_id
        )
        AS M
    ON 
        S1.product_stock_id=M.product_stock_id
    SET
        S1.product_size_quantity=S1.product_size_quantity+M.quantity;
    ELSE
    INSERT INTO
        product_stock (product_id,product_size,product_size_quantity)
        SELECT
            product_id,product_size, quantity
        FROM
            product_purchase_item
        WHERE
            product_purchase_item_id=NEW.product_purchase_item_id;
  END IF;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Problem show when it update same `product_id`'s different `product_size` on `product_stock`

Comment: Some sample data would help. One question - on your inner join where clause should contain product_too? i.e. like P.product_purchase_id = NEW.product_purchase_id AND s.product_id = NEW.product_id. Hope this helps

Comment: @AndaIancu I also add  S.product_id=NEW.product_id
   AND
   S.product_size=NEW.product_size but same problem

Comment: Consider to provide tables schema and sample data. It may considerably improve your chances of getting an answer you're looking for.

Comment: see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18537760/how-can-i-get-distinct-group-by-behavior-in-update-query/18542231?noredirect=1#18542231)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most suspicious subquery in your code is this one:

```
SET X = (SELECT product_size FROM product_stock WHERE product_id = NEW.product_id );
```

Do you have duplicates in the `product_stock` table?  This is easy to determine:

```
select product_id
from product_stock
group by product_id
having count(*) > 1;
```

If you do, you can select one of them as:

```
SET X = (SELECT product_size FROM product_stock WHERE product_id = NEW.product_id limit 1);
```

Comment: thanks it's work now. I change my X query is SET X = (SELECT product_size FROM product_stock WHERE product_id = NEW.product_id AND product_size=NEW.product_size);